# jQuery Mobile messing up my classes

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm creating the below which is doing fine except for one problem:

```
function showDevices() {
    for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
        var value = devices[i].Value;
        var geraete_id = devices[i].Key;
        if (value.Name != "") { // if name exists, use that as heading, else, use UDID
            $("#geraete-list").append("<li id='geraete-"+i+"'><a href='#'><h5>" + value.Name + "</h5>"
            + "<p>" + value.LastUsedBy + "</p>"
            + "<p id='geraete_DID'>" + geraete_id + "</p>"
            + "<p>Zuletzt Verwendet: " + formatDate(jsonToDate(value.LastUsed)) + "</p></a>"
            + "<a href='#confirm_device_removal' class='deleteListItem' data-rel='dialog'></a></li>");
        }
        else {
            $("#geraete-list").append("<li id='geraete-"+i+"'><a href='#'><h5 id='geraete_DID'>" + geraete_id + "</h5>"
                + "<p>" + value.LastUsedBy + "</p>"
                + "<p>Anonymous User</p>"
                + "<p>Zuletzt Verwendet: " + formatDate(jsonToDate(value.LastUsed)) + "</p></a>"
                + "<a href='#confirm_device_removal' class='deleteListItem' data-rel='dialog'></a></li>");

        }
    }
    $("#geraete-list").listview("refresh");
}
```

The problem is that `class='deleteListItem'gets` turned into `class='deleteListItem ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-delete'`

Is this just the way Chrome is reading it or is jQuery Mobile adding this into my class?

The problem is I want to run the below code but the `getDeviceIDforRemoval()` isn't doing anything...

```
function getDeviceIDforRemoval(){
    $(".device_to_remove").text($("#geraete_DID").text()); // sends the device ID into confirm submission dialog
}

function removeDevices(){
    var geraetID =  $(this).find('span').text(); //retrieves the DID inserted by above function
    removeDevice(geraetID,loadDevices);
}

function removeDevice(udid,onSuccess){
    Server.removeDevice(udid,onSuccess);
}
```

Comment: jQM added classes shouldn't affect the functions you have posted. make sure you aren't using same ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements can have multiple classes and when these are shown in the HTML they appear as

```
class="class1 class2 class3"
```

Order is largely unimportant.

This code...

```
 $(".device_to_remove").text($("#geraete_DID").text());
```

...will select all elements with class `device_to_remove` regardless of whether other classes are also applied to those elements. It will then attempt to set the `text` of those elements to the text of the element with id `geraete_DID`.

Which of your elements actually has the class `device_to_remove`? I see no other reference to this in your code?

Comment: @rory - Thanks for the tick, but can you comment on what your problem actually was? I didn't really provide a solution!

Comment: Thanks! The `device_to_remove` class is in a popup dialog. This is just a snippet from a larger block of code taht would be too long and messy to post here

Comment: Would downvoter can to explain what is wrong with my input? I was unable to provide a "solution" as not enough information was provided by the OP. I'm not expecting a response of course. Just whinging.

Comment: you answered my query regarding classes which was all I wanted to know at the time really. I'd have to post a hell of a lot of code to solve the big problem and I'd rather keep at it myself where possible. For now, I have eliminated a suspect so that's a start. Don't know who downvoted you though or why...

Comment: @rory That comment was aimed purely at the downvoter, it wasn't a criticism of your question! :)